# Motion layout start animation at start

Tags: android, animation, layout, motion

I've been watching motion animation layout videos and I've seen that the animation gets activated after a click or a swipe, how can I make the animation start when all the views have been created, like for example in a Hero Animation?

Comment: I have't tried it personally if it's working after a click how about calling performClick() on a view after allviews created?

Answer (score 1):

You could use methods `transitionToStart / transitionToEnd` on MotionLayout to perform animations from code. And therefore you can call this methods in `onStart/onResume` Fragment or Activity methods for example.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout#transitionToEnd()

Example:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Start animation programmatically after all views created
        motion_layout.transitionToEnd()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add code examples on how to use the code please?